# A database error is thrown, but mysql works

Tags: drush

I am using Drupal 7.54, Drush version 8.1.10, and MySQL version 5.7.17 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I mainly use drush for `drush up` to make sure my packages don't get too old.

Last week, everything was working.  Today, everything is still working on the website, and I can use `mysql -h localhost --user bar baz -p` (with the same info from the settings file) to log in successfully.  However, today, when I tried to run `drush up`, it gave me an error:

> Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more       [error]
>   functional Drupal environment to run this command.
>   The drush command 'up' could not be executed.                                                             [error]
>   Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                              [error]
>   Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
>    * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you
>   can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
>   parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
>    * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access
>   to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

When I run `drush up --debug`, the only additional piece of information is this error:

```
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_abc123 --database=obfuscated --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_def456
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

That makes it look like drush is trying to log in as root rather than as the user specified in the settings file, which is weird.

Between last week and this week, I **did** mess around with the database for an unrelated reason, so I'm sure I just messed something up there.

I tried rebooting the machine and restarting the MySQL service, and that didn't change anything.  I tried changing from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` per the drupal.org suggestion, but that didn't change anything.  `drush status` **is** pointing to the correct database even though the debug log makes it seem like it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, the issue was related to a bug in Drush.  https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2183 discusses an error where a `~/.my.cnf` file will interfere with Drush's database connection.

I didn't have a `~/.my.cnf`, but I did have a `~/.mylogin.cnf`.  When I moved that file, everything started working again.